# Install/Play Minecraft on Xubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, 13.04, xubuntu, java, minecraft

I´ve just installed Xubuntu and installed java on it and I can't play minecraft and have no idea how to install it! Could anyone help me!

Answer (score 0):

First unpack your downloaded package.
Open Minecraft with a right click on Minecraft.jar - open with - openJDKJava7Runtime.

In your homefolder will be created a .minecraft folder with game information.

Comment: It actually made it work till I pushed play because i got this error:
Game ended with bad state (exit code 134)